# Detect domain used to access EC2 instance behind Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS to host an EC2 instance. This instance uses a php application which would show different things depending on what domain is used to access the instance. For example, domain1.com and domain2.com both point to the same load balancer which sends the requests to the EC2 instance. I would like to know if the client is using domain1.com or domain2.com to access the instance so that I could show a different text or logo.

I checked X-Forwarded headers but they only seem to give me the clients ip http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html

I am **not** looking for the host name or ec2 domain.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` should be what you are looking for.  Check that?

Comment: Well, that works, I guess this is a duplicate otherwise feel free to put it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` will give the domain even if you are behind a load balancer on AWS.